# How to connect VB.net to SQL Server 2005 Express using Windows Authentication?

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005-express

```
 Public DbCon = "Data Source="";User ID="";Password="";Initial Catalog="";"
```

So far this is the code for SQL Server Authentication that I know.

I want to know the connection string for Windows Authentication

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code for an Sql Express connection on the local machine:

```
     Public DbCon = "Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

The 2005 specific connection string is:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Unless you have specified an instance name during SQL Express setup, in which case use:

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```